# Concep of c# Dictionary in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dictionary

I'm trying to implement the concept of dictionary which i use in c# in order to collect multiple records based on multiple id's. But i hardly find any such thing in codeigniter framework. What I have is a Course table and another table naming course_prices. Now each course has multiple prices. And I'm trying to display using bootstrap according having course name as title of header accordion and list of prices on the content div.

As i couldn't find the concept of dictionary here, i tried with writing join query but that wouldn't help. The details of courses are repeated.

Below is my code

```
$this->load->model('Courses_model', 'Courses');

        $model = $this->Courses;

        $records = $model->setAlias('c')
                        ->find()
                        ->select('c.*,cp.Id as PriceId')
                        ->join('course_price AS cp', 'c.id = cp.CourseId')
                        ->get()
                        ->result_array();
```

And this is the view

```
<?php if(empty($courses)){ print_r("no class available"); } else{ print_r($courses); foreach ($courses as $k => $course) { ?>

                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<?=$k?>">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion9" href="#collapse<?=$k?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne9">
                                           <?= $course->name ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapse<?=$k?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?=$k?>">
                                    <div class="panel-body">

                                      <?php foreach ($course->course_price as $key => $price) {?>
                                      <div class="custom-controls-stacked">
                                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                            <input name="class" id="class_1<?= $k ?>" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="<?= $price->PriceId; ?>" required> 
                                            <label for="class_<?= $k ?>" class="custom-control-label">Drop In Price <?= $course->price ?></label>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php } }?>
```

[image]

Comment: The C#'s concept for Dictionnary is similar to what's named a Map in other languages, isn't it? If so, you could use the PHP's array. The array is a mix between _array_, _vector_ and _map_.

Comment: We (PHP people) just call them arrays with string keys, lol.  or Associative arrays.

Comment: So PHP coders, how do i apply the above scenario using Associative arrays or array mapping?

Comment: `<?= $course->name ?>` might want some semi-colons there....  And these ID's will probably be duplicate `id="class_1<?= $k ?>"` `$k` is the key of the outer loop the one over `$courses` that I almost didn't see.  So when you loop with the inner loop `$k` doesn't change.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Good eye :)

Comment: It's just like this loop `foreach ($course->course_price as $key => $price)`  except the elements are probably not objects.  So you just use `$course['PriceId']` for example.  If they are objects then you use the arrow `->`  Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to use it as an object because for each course multiple prices has to be listed.

Comment: If you have data from the DB like this `$course = [['foo'=>'bar0'], ['foo'=>'bar1']]` or a typical DB result.  Then you loop with `foreach ($course as $key => $row)` - row is equal to `['foo'=>'bar0']` and you can access `foo` like this `$row['foo']`  Or if it's an object `$row->foo` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190498/discussion-between-salar-muhammad-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: I don't even see `$course` being assigned anywhere, you have `$records` - I suggest doing some basic tutorials on arrays in PHP.  It's to broad and unclear what your asking.

Comment: Please come on chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190498/discussion-between-salar-muhammad-and-artisticphoenix